# First two entrys of a hashmap Java

Tags: java, hashmap

is there a way, i can get the first two entrys of a hashmap? I tried it like this, but it doesnt work

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : m.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            m.remove(entry.getKey(), entry.);
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _first two entries_ in `HashMap` which is famous for its undefined order of elements?

Comment: A `HashMap` doesn’t impose an order on the entries. so what do you mean by the first two? The first two that were ever added to the map? The first two according to some sort order of the keys? Something else?

Comment: Try `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want any two values from the map:

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> m = Map.of(6, 9, 1, 3, 4, 2);
    
    Iterator<Integer> intIterator = m.values().iterator();
    if (intIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(intIterator.next());
        if (intIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(intIterator.next());
            
        }
    }
```

Output on my Java 11:

> ```
> 2
> 9
> ```

You notice that the values printed not the first two (in any sense that I have come to think of).

If you want the first two entries added to the map, use a `LinkedHashMap`. It maintains insertion order by default.

If you want the values corresponding to the two smallest keys, use streams:

```
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> smallest = m.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .min(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .orElseThrow();
    Integer secondSmallest = m.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> ! e.getKey().equals(smallest.getKey()))
            .min(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .orElseThrow();
    
    System.out.println("" + smallest.getValue() + ' ' + secondSmallest);
```

> 3 2

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about **finding** but your code is about **removing**.  In general, if you want to remove entries from a collection you're iterating over, tread very carefully.

The docmentation for a HashMap explicit prohibits what you are doing.

> public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
>
> If the
> map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except
> through the iterator's own remove operation, or through the setValue
> operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the results of the
> iteration are undefined.

The generally-safe method is to use an explicit iterator, and use the [iterator's remove method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--).